# Anypoint Studio 6.6.8 local run in debug mode calls monitor immediately and stop responding

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have a problem once updated AnyPoint Studio to 6.6.8 (was fine on 6.6.7) but not sure if that because of that or some setting I am missing.
So I have a project domain and dependent on one package, once I do run for debug, and got message its deployed successfully - all calls from postman are happening fine, however very often immediately after it deployed starting `app.deployer.monitor.1` and once he do that ever he wants its stop responding from postman. Before update if I change something in flow and save that monitor process was engaged but it keep responding to postman calls. Could you advice how to find what is wrong, for me is seems like listener start listening on another port or something, no warnings or error in console then monitor rerun. Only postman: "Connection refused". If no run postman give no listener available and that's correct. Any advice?

upd: that I can see in a console then monitor start running without any change in a flow:
[image]

Comment: You should provide all the code from the projects (domains, apps), screenshots of the status of the debugger and some thread dumps of good/bad situations to analyze. Probably this issue is not a good match for Stackoverflow. Have you tried with the latest Studio 6 release (6.6.10 at this time)? You should always use the latest release anyway to get the latest fixes.

Comment: using that is given by bank :) cant show code :( under DND, just need maybe some guidance where I may potentially to look for, as others seems not having problem with such only my Studio acting weird

Comment: Other than use the last version of Studio and ensure that execution is not stopped in a breakpoint I'm not sure if any other suggestion that can be useful. Remember that the guidelines of Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) explicitly say "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example." otherwise they are not in scope and could be closed.

Comment: yes, but that question is not how to debug itself but because of the way how AnyPoint run runtime, that i am try to find is it any settings or conditions then this monitor starting and how to stop it as its definitely somewhere on the project but not sure where.

Comment: I know and understand the difference. This issue is like debugging Anypoint Studio without having a why to reproduce the issue.

Comment: glad for you help, you already did that for me many times, really appreciated, what I cant find in documentation how this monitor stuff is engaging, as I have other packages and its run only if I do run and then update flow and save it, but for this one its run immediately after start building so I expect maybe its some settings or option what control that and get failed some how only for this one package in my case.

Comment: I'm not aware of an issue related to app.deployer.monitor. Maybe the issue is unrelated and there is no connection. I don't have that problem either. Try at least sharing the lines in the log that mention it. Have you tried my previous suggestion to upgrade Studio?

Comment: will update with some depersonalised logs on Monday, I cant roll back, as upgrade was done for whole team but only for me its not working as it should and in one case only, so its kind of my problem not organisation as priority low and it support cant help, so try my self :)

Comment: updated with a log example, seems its not happy with log4j setup but still not sure how to stop this monitor starting by itself...

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for logs and code. Add the text.

Comment: I cant copy text from VDI :(

Comment: That's a limitation to be able to help. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason text is required in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even if no answer so far where is a place to control that mysterious monitor behaviour, issue with immediately start was solved after completely deleted workspace and rebuild it on first run, now its acting as it should, hope it may help somebody so don't deleting my question.